# How send request with AFNetworking 2 in strict sequential order?

Tags: asynchronous, synchronization, afnetworking-2

I'm doing the sync to mirror a sqlite DB to a server one.

I have a Master-Detail table, where the details must be send to the server ASAP. However, is possible that detail 3 arrive before detail 2. I need to mimic the steps made to the document and respect the order of the operations.

When a record is saved locally, I send a notification and then post the data. How I can guarantee a strict sequential order using AFNetworking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, operations run concurrently, with no guarantee of order. The only way to ensure that actions play is to prevent more than one request operation from running at a given time, by setting the `operationQueue.maximumConcurrentOperations` property to `1` *(or, if you're not using a manager, make sure to enqueue operations into an operation queue with the property set thusly)*.

Comment: It is possible to force dependencies though. Se [Queue HTTP Operations With AFNetworking](http://samwize.com/2013/03/02/queue-http-operations-with-afnetworking/)