# Does AFHTTPRequestOperationManager run requests on the operationQueue?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, afnetworking

If I have a manager created and instance-varred and I do:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self.manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:mySuccessBlock failure:myFailureBlock];

[operation start];
```

will this run on the manager's operationQueue?  I can't seem to find anything guaranteeing it will verse using one of the GET, POST, PUT methods instead which I assume will add the operation to the queue.

I see mattt's answer here, but I want to be sure one way or the other.

[How send request with AFNetworking 2 in strict sequential order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585471/how-send-request-with-afnetworking-2-in-strict-sequential-order)

What I'm trying to do is queue up requests and have them run synchronously by setting

```
[self.manager.operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to run an operation on a queue, you have to explicitly add the operation to the queue:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self.manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:mySuccessBlock failure:myFailureBlock];

[queue addOperation:operation];
```

This presumes that you would create a queue:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
queue.name = @"com.domain.app.networkQueue";
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
```

If you just start the operations without adding them to a queue (e.g. `[operation start]`), they'll just run, without honoring any particular queue parameters.

Note, you could also have added your operation to the operation manager's queue (which you can set the `maxConcurrentOperationCount`, as you alluded to in your question):

```
[self.manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

That saves you from having to create your own queue. But it then presumes that *all* of your other AFNetworking requests for this `manager` would also run serially, too. Personally, I'd leave `manager.operationQueue` alone, and create a dedicated queue for my logic that required serial operations.

One final note: Using serial network operations imposes a significant performance penalty over concurrent requests. I'll assume from your question that you absolutely need to do it serially, but in general I now design my apps to use concurrent requests wherever possible, as it's a much better UX. If I need a particular operation to be serial (e.g. the login), then I do that with operation dependencies or completion blocks, but the rest of the app is running concurrent network requests wherever possible.